# Can't use vue component in my Rails5 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I'm new to vue.js and webpack configuration.

I can use Vue instance in `app/javascript/packs/somecode.js`.

But I can't render `*.vue` file. If I add any `*.vue` file to `app/javascript/packs/components/` directory,

it says

"module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. ".

But I didnt create any new option.

### environment

ruby

```
ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

rails

```
5.1.0
```

app.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: "Hello Vue!"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

console.log in my chrome browser

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./app/javascript/packs/app.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /Users/shiho/dev/appname/app/javascript/packs/app.vue: Unknown option: base.omit. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.

A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`

For more detailed information on preset configuration, please see http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#pluginpresets-options.
    at Logger.error (/Users/shiho/dev/appname/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:41:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/shiho/dev/appname/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:226:20)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/shiho/dev/appname/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (/Users/shiho/dev/appname/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
    at new File (/Users/shiho/dev/appname/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/shiho/dev/appname/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (/Users/shiho/dev/appname/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:50:20)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/shiho/dev/appname/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:173:20)
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/app.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 1:0-178 1:199-374
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/app.vue
```

.babelrc

```
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": "> 1%",
        "uglify": true
      },
      "useBuiltIns": true
    }]
  ],

  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }]
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.4.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "coffeescript": "1.12.7",
    "intro.js": "^2.8.0-alpha.1",
    "rails-ujs": "^5.2.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.3.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.0.0-rc.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "scripts": {}
}
```

config/webpacker.yml

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .vue
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: /node_modules/


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true

staging:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

config/webpack/development.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

Comment: Hmm,try to give another name.Not App.vue because App.vue exists

Comment: I tried but same error persists. I found that if I remove `<script>`tag and only add `<template>` to *.vue file, compiling success. but I dont know why adding `<script>` to vue component makes compile fails.

Comment: What happens if you move components out of /packs and into /javascript/components?

Comment: I tried your idea, but same error persists.

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./app/javascript/components/Item.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /Users/shiho/dev/myapp/app/javascript/components/Item.vue: Unknown option: base.omit. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.

Comment: I found that if i change `var loaderOptions = loaderUtils.getoptions(this) || {}` to `var loaderOptions ={}` in node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js , error dissapears.

Comment: try yarn add babel-runtime

Comment: same error persists after running `yarn add babel-runtime` and `yarn add babel-loader`. 
`Unknown option: base.omit. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.`