# bin/webpack error while introducing VueJS to Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js

I'm trying to introduce Vue.JS by webpack. Now I'm struggling with an error while I execute `bin/webpack`.

The issue is similar to this one ([Can't use vue component in my Rails5 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953292/cant-use-vue-component-in-my-rails5-app)) but seems slightly different, as nothing will be changed if I remove tag in "/app/javascript/app.vue".

The gem file is below:

`gem 'webpacker', github: 'rails/webpacker'`

And the below is "/config/webpack/webpacker.yml":

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .vue
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: /node_modules/


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

### Error:

```
$ bin/webpack
(node:24139) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Hash: 609c54cf56c50ef7c14a
Version: webpack 3.12.0

Time: 1760ms
                                         Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                 hello-3fc5abe86ea1eca80c8f.js     248 kB       0  [emitted]  hello
           application-12a437e15157c0d4029c.js    3.27 kB       1  [emitted]  application
    hello-9cb5a7334a6577c3422968b9b9970b2f.css  134 bytes       0  [emitted]  hello
             hello-3fc5abe86ea1eca80c8f.js.map     293 kB       0  [emitted]  hello
hello-9cb5a7334a6577c3422968b9b9970b2f.css.map  557 bytes       0  [emitted]  hello
       application-12a437e15157c0d4029c.js.map    3.19 kB       1  [emitted]  application
                                 manifest.json  402 bytes          [emitted]
   [0] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] ./app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 362 bytes {0} [built]
   [2] ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=scrip
t&lang=js 1.66 kB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
   [3] ./node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/loader.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/style-loader??ref--4-1!./node_modules/css-loader
??ref--1-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--1-3!./node_modules/vue-loader/
lib??vue-loader-options!./app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=6fb8108a&scoped=true&lang=css 41 bytes {0} [built]
   [4] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 515 bytes {1} [built]
   [5] ./app/javascript/packs/hello.js 1.93 kB {0} [built]
  [10] ./app/javascript/app.vue 978 bytes {0} [built]
[11] ./app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=template&id=6fb8108a&scoped=true 212 bytes {0} [built]
  [12] ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./app

/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=template&id=6fb8108a&scoped=true 749 bytes {0} [built]
  [13] ./app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=6fb8108a&scoped=true&lang=css 896 bytes {0} [built]
    + 5 hidden modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=scr
ipt&lang=js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /Users/hogehoge//app/javascript/app.vue: Unknown option: base.omit. C
heck out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.

A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`
For more detailed information on preset configuration, please see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins#pluginpresets-options.
    at Logger.error (/Users/hogehoge/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:41:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/hogehoge/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option

-manager.js:226:20)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/hogehoge/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager
.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (/Users/hogehoge/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
    at new File (/Users/hogehoge/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/hogehoge/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (/Users/hogehoge/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:50:20)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/hogehoge/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:173:20)
 @ ./app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 1:0-172 1:193-362
 @ ./app/javascript/app.vue
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/hello.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/loader.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/style-loader??ref--4-1!./node_modules/css-load
er??ref--1-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--1-3!./node_modules/vue-loade
r/lib??vue-loader-options!./app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=6fb8108a&scoped=true&lang=css
Module build failed: ValidationError: Style Loader Invalid Options

options['ident'] is an invalid additional property

 @ ./app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=6fb8108a&scoped=true&lang=css 1:0-439 1:460-896
 @ ./app/javascript/app.vue
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/hello.js
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--1-2!node_modules/vu
e-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??ref--1-3!node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loade
r-options!app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=6fb8108a&scoped=true&lang=css:
       [0] ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--1-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?
?ref--1-3!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./app/javascript/app.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=6fb8108a&scoped=true&lang=c
ss 789 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
```

If you have any advice that would be so helpful.

Comment: we're going to need to see your webpack config

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've updated the information.